# Paraphrase or a clear translation

Tags: meaning, translation

> Coop died, *streaming with dysentery over a slit trench in an agony of jabbering delirium*, killed by dehydration.

In the sentence above, the italicized phrase between two commas is confusing. What is a basic-English translation that might be easier to understand?

Comment: "*Coop pooped himself to death.*"

Comment: Please specify what *exactly* you find confusing, which words exactly you do not understand, which dictionaries you have looked them up in, what exactly they said, and why exactly you think their definitions don't fit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might be clearer with a few more commas

```
Coop died,                          --->  Coop Died
streaming with dysentery            --->    from diarrhea
over a slit trench                  --->    while using a primitive trench toilet
in an agony of jabbering delerium   --->    in pain and mad with fever
killed by dehydration               --->  killed by dehydration.
```

Comment: thanks for you clarifications. but I found this definition for "slit trench" in Oxford English Dictionary: a narrow trench for a soldier or a small group of soldiers and their equipment.       and now you say this. that was quite interesting for me.so in this case it is completely different! how it come?!

Answer (score 0):

"Slit trench" never means "primitive trench toilet". I think you just got confused by OldCat's answer.

Your sentence means

> Coop died, delirious from dehydration, while defecating in a trench (doesn't necessarily have to be the same trench him and his allies dug).

I think OldCat just tried to explain to you that it was common during trench warfare to defecate somewhere within the trench since you couldn't exactly walk around to find a nice spot.

Answer (score 0):

Coop was straddling the trench as if it were a primitive latrine. The preposition "over" tells us this.